# Reversing SVD back to the original variables

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

I have a data matrix $M$ that has $n$ samples (rows) described by $m$ variables (columns) $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_m$. I do a SVD to reduce the $m$ dimensions to just 3 dimensions. I understand that the $x,y,z$ coordinates (i.e., the SVD values) are calculated from the eigenvectors of $MM^T$.

My question is, if I pick an arbitrary point in the SVD space (i.e. a value for SVD1, SVD2, SVD3, not necessarily in the data), is there a convenient way to translate that back to a set of the original variables (i.e., $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_m$)?

Comment: Please use math typesetting. More information: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "Reducing $m$ via SVD to 3" means that you take the first three terms from the [dyadic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Applications_of_the_SVD) of the matrix $X=(X_1, X_2, \dotsc ,X_m)$? Also, when you write the SVD values, I am not sure what is matrix $T$ and I assume that $M=X$, right?
"By picking arbitrary point in SVD" you mean taking an arbitrary 3-dimensional vector? Please, try to specify these questions, I am very confused by the presented question in that form.

Comment: M represents the(nxm) matrix.MT represents the matrix transpose. Yes, the arbitrary point refers to an arbitrary 3-dimensional vector in the new vector space.

Comment: Please edit your question to more clearly reflect your intent

Comment: @chetak Your question has been closed as a duplicate, please take a look there and feel free to ask any additional questions if you have any. I wrote my answer there trying to take your question into account as well. I have a section about SVD in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. Take a look at this picture:

[image: SVD]

In this case, we have two dimensions. Let's say we reduce it to 1 (just $U_1$). What will happen is that all the points will be projected onto $U_1$ so many points (an infinite number, in fact) will map to the *same* point on $U_1$. The same will happen with any dimensionality reduction via SVD.

Comment: Sure, so in your example above how do I transform the "same point on U1" to a point on the original axis. I understand that this would be an approximation but I'd like to understand the formula behind the transformation. See "inverse_transform" in scikit - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.inverse_transform

Comment: @chetak conceptually, you take that point on $U_1$ and see where it is on the $L$ and $W$ axis. You can see how scikit-learn does it by looking at the source of the "inverse_transform" function. If you have a row-vector $X=[x_1,x_2,...x_k]$ (where $k$ is the number of dimensions you reduced to) then you can multiply it by the $k \times n$ matrix where each row is one of the eigen-vector. Note that scikit learn Let's $X$ be a matrix with any number of rows and $k$ columns - in this case, each row is a point that is being transformed back to the original space.

Comment: thanks @roundsquare, what will be an intuitive explanation for this multiplication? – chetak